# How to ignore .git folder when using NPM del

Tags: npm, glob, del

This is probably stupid easy, but I'm having serious difficulties finding the answer. I want to delete everything in a folder except the .git folder. I'm calling it as such:

```
return del([
    buildTo + "/**",
    "!" + buildTo + "/.git"
], { force: true });
```

I've tried that and a few other things to no avail. The .git folder keeps getting deleted. What's the correct way to not delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was stupid easy. I forgot the "/*" at the end and didn't even need the ignore:

```
return del([
    buildTo + "/**/*"
], { force: true });
```